# Replacing elements in a matrix in C

Tags: c

I need to check whether the elements on the main diagonal of a matrix are even and divisible into sum of its indexes. I remembered such elements in an 1-D array:

```
for (i=0; i<n; ++i)
for (j=0; j<m; ++j)
    {
        if ((i == j) && ((arr[i][j] % 2) == 0))
            {
            arr2[count] = arr[i][j]; 
            ++count;
            break;
            }
    }
```

Then I replace the elements which satisfy the condition with the sum of its indexes and place a special condition for [0][0] because of dividing on 0:

```
    count = 0;
for (i=0; i<n; ++i)
for (j=0; j<m; ++j)
    {
        if ((i+j != 0) && (arr[i][j] == arr2[count]) && ((arr[i][j] % (i+j)) == 0))
            {
            arr[i][j] = i+j;
            ++count;
            }
        else if (((i+j) == 0) && (arr[i][j] == arr2[count])) arr[i][j] = 0;
    }
```

The trouble is that when the first element is even, it is the only replaced number, and the condition doesn't work for the other elements:

[image: Sorry for this color]

Comment: i suggest you split our problems and checks . For example: main diagonal of a matrix are even and divisible into sum of its indexes. You correctly check for diagonal with i==j, and %2. However you are not checking the sum of the indices i+j. Why do you have **break** after the first check. That seems like a code left-over from some testing...

Comment: What is the type of `arr`?  Is it an array of float, double, or perhaps int?  If you post complete code, such questions vanish.

Comment: Arr is a 2-D array of integers

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text, post text as text. And format your C code in a similar way as the samples in your C text book.

Comment: you have break on the first loop . However, why bother looping trough the whole matrix when you care only about the diagonal ? (the definition of MAIN diagonal for non-square matrix conveniently is i==j). So you can use a single for loop from 0 to n-1 and check arr[i][i].

Comment: (i+j) == 0 makes sure the second if works only on the first element.

Comment: It's an overkill and a waste of time to scan the whole n-by-m array and filter it with `i==j` (at least for big values of `n` and `m`). If you want to check diagonal elements, do just that - simply scan the diagonal! `for (i=0; i<n && i<m; i++) { process(arr[i][i]); }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Problem:

`arr2` is not filled appropriately. As soon as you fill one element into it, you break out of that loop. Notice the usage of `break` in that loop. Moreover, you did not update the value of `count` in that else-if condition which causes your loop to run in vain searching for `arr2[0]` throughout.

## Solution:

1. Remove that `break` statement.
2. Add `++count` into that else-if condition.

**Bonus:**

You have written ugly code. You used an extra array which adds to the space complexity of your code and you have too many loops which increases the time complexity as well. You will understand these things later as you progress but for now, I'll give you a better solution:

```
// Deal with the (0, 0) case outside the loop
// And avoid an extra else-if inside the loop
if (arr[0][0] % 2 == 0)
    arr[0][0] = 0;

// There are n diagonal elements in a matrix of order n
// Row and column indexes of a diagonal element are equal
// So you can eliminate the use of j and just rely on i  
for (i = 1; i < n; ++i)
    // Check if the diagonal element is even and divisible by the sum of the indices
    if (arr[i][i] % 2 == 0 && arr[i][i] % (i + i) == 0)
        // Replace the element if the condition is satisfied
        arr[i][i] = i + i;
```

As you can see, this approach does not require any extra space and runs in a very good linear time. You may further optimize it by checking if a number is not odd using bitwise AND `!(i & 1)`, and changing `i + i` into `2 * i` which can be done quickly using the bitwise left shift operator `(i << 1)`.

By the way, why do you want `arr[0][0]` to be replaced? [Division by 0 is undefined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_by_zero).

Comment: The compiler's very likely to optimize the modulo into an AND and the multiplication into a shift anyway. I would suggest writing idiomatic code instead.

Comment: @S.S.Anne Oh yeah, that was just an additional piece of knowledge for the OP :P